# Wpf ListBox single click event

Tags: wpf, listbox

In my wpf application using mvvm , and when the user click any item on listbox, then i want to show a pop up window. i tried,

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenPopUpCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

When user double click the item, pop up window showing. Is there is any way to show the pop up window with a single mouse click?

Comment: Try "MouseLeftButtonUp"

Comment: Or 'PreviewMouseDown' event